# How to switch columns of csv file (c#)

Tags: c#

I have a 5 column CSV file and I need to bring the third column to the front.

How do I do this?
Below is what I think I have to do.

```
     //Basically I have to make a fore loop which results in a multidimensional array
        //Then write another for loop switching the colums of the array around
        //Then sorting it
        //then saving it
```

Update: The csv file is as follows

string,string, double, double, string

E.g

John,Smith,.464,10.5, words and whatnot

Also should have mentioned that this process needs to be reversible, meaning that the moved column needs to be put back where it was from.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can do this with C#, this is your mission if you choose to accept it

Comment: Indeed, it should be fairly straight forward but I have a feeling it will be a bit of resource intensive task if the file is too big!

Comment: @AD8 yes, bigger the file is heavier the code will be. but that penalty is worth carrying if you have not make CSV in proper order in first place (if this task is production task).

Comment: @Gooyan, could you please add a few records of the file that you need to have updated?

Comment: You need to (1) Load the CSV as a list of records, (2) transpose the fields, (3) save the records as a new CSV. That's all.

Comment: @Gooyan one of the idea can be, read chunk of records (say 1000) into data from csv, then from datatable you can rearrange it easily and write into file, which will free up memory, then again read next chunk, load into datatable,rearrange and append to the file. For speed, you can make parallel calls to generate read 1000 record chunk and create small multiple csv files and finally merge in one shot.

Comment: Open the file with your favorite spreadsheet program, drag the third column to the left, create a sort on whatever you want, save, job done.

Comment: Example with 3 fields and Linq: `var d = lines.Select<string, string[]>(x => x.Split(','))
    .Select( x => (new Tuple<string, string, string>( x[1], x[0], x[2])  )  )
    .ToList();`

Comment: @Spotted what if he has to make a program for that to submit somewhere ? :D

Comment: @Amit We programmers tend to over-engineer everything. Since OP never stated if and why he needs to do that as a program, I prefer to propose the simplest matching solution (as ironic as it may seem).

Comment: @Spotted of course, I agree with you.. but if someone is asking a help from programmer, programmer will always think that he wants a program for that .. No!!!

Comment: @Amit [Spreasheet is programming](https://vimeo.com/162206549)

Comment: @Spotted yes but you didn't suggested to program a macro in excel :D and if I am opening an excel and closing it.. i m not programming :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple read write loop should get the job done, without needing to load all the data into memory.

**Note:** The solution below assumes a simple CSV file, where fields do not contain the delimiter (",") and each row contains the same number of columns.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Move a csv file column to a new position. File is modified in place.
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveCsvColumn(string file, int column, int position, string delimeter = ",")
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write)))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                // Read the line
                var line = reader.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                // Move the column within the array of columns
                MoveColumn(line, column, position);

                // write the output
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(delimeter, line));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Move a column within the array to the new destination
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveColumn(object[] line, int from, int to)
    {
        to = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(line.Length - 1, to));

        if (from == to 
            || from < 0 
            || from >= line.Length)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (from != to)
        {
            if (from > to)
            {
                // percolate down
                Swap(line, from, from-1);
                from--;
            }
            else
            {
                // percolate up
                Swap(line, from, from + 1);
                from++;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Swap values positions within the array
    /// </summary>
    public void Swap(object[] line, int a, int b)
    {
        var tmp = line[a];
        line[a] = line[b];
        line[b] = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Initially I posted my solution in the comments but I think it deserves a proper answer.

> I have a 5 column CSV file and I need to bring the third column to the front. How do I do this?

1. Open the file with your favorite spreadsheet program
2. Drag the third column to the left
3. (Create a sort on whatever you want)
4. Save
5. Job done

Now some readers may argue that the question was tagged with `C#` and thus my answer would be invalid. I'm arguing that OP never provided any evidence that such a task has to be resolved by a programming language (think [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/)), thus making acceptable answer as vague as OP's question (spreadsheet programs beeing eligible for such an answer).

@Gooyan Feel free to update your question with more details on what (and why) you need to achieve that, what you already tried (if anything) and I will gladly update my answer accordingly.